# Transfer data into column head and assign the value in panda

Tags: python, dataframe

Given a dataframe:

| name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xx | a | 1 |
| yy | b | 2 |

how do I transfer it into:

| name | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xx | 1 | 0 |
| yy | 0 | 2 |

Only come up with the idea where I created new column and assign the value based on 'type' column.

df.loc[df.type == 'a', 'a'] =  df['value']

then fill na

repeat until all types are processed.

I can feel there must be a better solution just cannot find any reference. Any hint please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df = df.pivot(index='type', columns='name', values='value').rename_axis(None)
df = df.transpose().fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints

```
  name  a  b
0   xx  1  0
1   yy  0  2
```

csv I used

```
name,type,value
xx,a,1
yy,b,2
```

Comment: Thanks!! pivot is the one I am looking for!!